# How to split a hash in two hashes based on a condition?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
input = {"a"=>"440", "b"=>"-195", "c"=>"-163", "d"=>"100"}
```

From it I want to get two hashes, one containing the pairs whose value (as integer) is positive, the other containing negative values, for example:

```
positive = {"a"=>"440", "d"=>"100" } 
negative = {"b"=>"-195", "c"=>"-163" }
```

How can I achieve this using the minimum amount of code?

Comment: It is not clear if you want to separate even/odd values or positive/negative values.

Comment: I want positive and negative.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`Enumerable#partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method to split an enumerable object (like a hash) based on a condition. For example, to separate positive/negative values:

```
input.partition { |_, v| v.to_i < 0 }
# => [[["b", "-195"], ["c", "-163"]], 
#     [["a", "440"], ["d", "100"]]]
```

Then, to get the desired result, you can use `map` and `to_h` to convert the key/value arrays to hashes:

```
negative, positive = input.partition { |_, v| v.to_i < 0 }.map(&:to_h)
positive
# => {"a"=>"440", "d"=>"100"}
negative
# => {"b"=>"-195", "c"=>"-163"}
```

If you use a version of Ruby prior 2.1 you can replace the `Array#to_h` method (that was introduced in Ruby 2.1) like this:

```
evens, odds = input.partition { |_, v| v.to_i.even? }
               .map { |alist| Hash[alist] }
```

Comment: `partition` is better... m'hai fregatoooo :D

Answer (score 1):

This implementation uses [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
input = {"a"=>"440", "b"=>"-195", "c"=>"-163", "d"=>"100"}
grouped = input.group_by { |_, v| v.to_i >= 0 }.map { |k, v| [k, v.to_h] }.to_h
positives, negatives = grouped.values
positives #=> {"a"=>"440", "d"=>"100"}
negatives #=> {"b"=>"-195", "c"=>"-163"}
```

I must say that `Enumerable#partition` is more appropriate, as @toro2k answered.

Answer (score 0):

something like this then?

```
positive = Hash.new
negative = Hash.new

input.each_pair  { |var,val|
  if val.to_i > 0 
    positive[var] = val
  else
    negative[var] = val
  end
}
```